# Image move left on hover

Tags: image, hover, position, padding, transition

I'm new to webdesign, and i have a particular example, ok i got stuck here:
You have 3 images combining the logo, and when you go hover the middle image, side ones spreed for like 50px on each side. I've achieved the goal to move image on right side with padding but when i try to do the same for left side, my image start to jump left and back to original place.

If some1 has better suggestion i love to study it.

This is an [example](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/233/exampleuu.png/) of what I wish to achieve.

I came up with this code:

```
    #logo_levo{
        position: absolute;
        float: right;
        width: 111px;
        height: 111px;
        -moz-transition:all 0.3s linear;

    }
    #logo_levo:hover{
        padding-right: 100px;
    }
```

html:

```
<img id="logo_levo" src="data/images/Class_B_obroc1_logo.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

okay here's something you can work on. css rules on fiddle..check the fiddle

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RruZ7/)

```
<div id='logo'>
  <div id='a'></div><!--left image-->
  <div id='b'></div><!--middle image-->
  <div id='c'></div><!--right image-->
</div>
```